# Principal Variation Search almost always twice as fast as Alpha-Beta without move ordering?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I have a weird problem. According to wikipedia and other sources Principal Variation Search should give about 10% improvement in chess. 
I've tested these two algorithms and to my surprise, PVS was in 90% of the cases much faster than Alpha-Beta, even without any move ordering. I'm using random generated tree with random breadth (within some range like from 4 to 20) and random values (within some range too e.g. 1-100). I also perform the tests in Java, not C or C++. Does any of these facts can explain this weird advantage of PVS versus Alpha-Beta?

Comment: How complex is your evaluation function yet? If you are only evaluating material, this IS realistic.

Comment: I don't have any evaluation function because I perform these test just for fun, I'm not making a chess program. What I do is that I create a random tree with a random number of nodes and a depth between 5-10. I assign end nodes a random value between 1-1000 (these could represent the value of a given board (position of figures) in chess from a perspective of one player but as I've said I don't bother with any evaluation functions so the value of end-nodes do not reflect any board position but are randomly generated numbers within 1-1000 instead... [continued]

Comment: ... By "no move ordering" I meant that I don't manipulate the values of the end-nodes or their order - they are all randomly generated numbers. How can you explain the advantage of PVS over alpha-beta in this case? I'd say that PVS have to do "more work" here than alpha-beta but in 90% of the tests PVS wins, sometimes being even twice as fast. I used these pseudocodes: PVS : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_variation_search Alpha-Beta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning

Comment: @ Richard S Are you aware that PCS and iterative deepening are pointless when you generate Random numbers? PVS works because you excpect  the 1 ply deeper search to give a similar result as the less deep search (this is usually true for chess, won't work with random numbers though. Therefore, I am pretty sure that there is a mistake in your code.

Comment: You would never use random move ordering in a real game program, but try to find a good move early to weed out all the bad ones. For example, if there is a PxQ possible, that will never ever be tried last. If you do that, the results are not that interesting.

Comment: @xXliolauXx - Thanks for the response. I think I understand it now. So your reasoning is that if a make a move which scores high (i.e. the board position is favorable to me) and the other moves from that position (i.e. child nodes) are also good and so on, then the probability that the next moves from these positions will also leave me in a good position is high so this move is worth checking out so I may order this move to be the first one for PVS to analyze. And in case of random numbers you never know if the child nodes would be as good as the parent node so using PVS is absurd in that case

Comment: Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: And by the way, you were right, there was a mistake in my code - PVS isn't twice as fast as alpha-beta in case of random numbers. My new bug-free (hopefully) code shows that with completely random numbers within some range PVS is about 40% slower. I know that depth and breadth are also important but, rougly speaking, 40% sounds realistic, right?

Comment: @Rich Yes, your reasoning as absolutely correct. 40% Slower seems to be a little bit extreme, but it's possible since the rest of your program is way faster (or at least I guess it is) than a normal chessprogramm (where there are tonns of eules to be checked, while you are doing most stuff with rabdomness) Therefore, the small speed penalty of PVS usually is less than the speed gain from the ordering. In your case though, the does not yield any speed gain, and the penalty for it is more significant. Still, 40% seems to be very high for pvs.

Comment: If you think about it, with random move ordering, you'd expect that when you're exploring a PV or fail-low node N, you'd be making a ton of pointless null-move traversals.  (You could find exactly how many pointless traversals you'd make by figuring out how many times as you're iterating through `i=1` through `i=N-1` that the current child has a higher value than one that was previously visited.)  Further, the average cost of the traversal would go up as well because every child node would also make pointless traversals.

Comment: Lastly, you have some parameters that you've set that would affect how much random move ordering would cost, but you might not have set them in a way that exactly matches what they look like in a real chess game.  You say 4-20 breath (pun not intended) but you don't mention depth.  If your search depth is greater than a normal chess engine (which would be hard to determine because a real chess engine has ways of dynamically deciding when it can reduce search depth) then the penalty would be even higher.  Fun experiment though.  Keep up the hacking!